# Accessing react components directly from URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to create an new react app. I have 3 components: app (with login functionality) , admin and client.

- How can I render (redirect to) admin / client based on a value (user role) , after successfully login?
- Is this any way to access the admin / client components directly from the URL? More specific, localhost:3000 takes me to App.js (witch makes sense, because it is defined like this in index.js). If I want to see directly the admin component (hijacking the login), can I use for example localhost:3000/admin ? how can I do that?

Thank you !

Comment: What do you think to save role property in JWT token and read him from token? If a value from token admin, redirect to ``/admin`` otherwise ``/client`` etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use [react router](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react-js-routing) and in particular `route.push('/admin')`
- You need to [define the '/admin' route](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react-js-routing) and voilà.

To bypass the login, you may want to make a 'test-admin' route and a private 'admin' route. Here is how to make a private route if you happen to need it:

https://dev.to/karanpratapsingh/private-public-and-restricted-routes-in-react-42ff

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/), that allow to define some route based on URL.
When you have a login feature, then you would probably wants to have some protected route, that are only accessible when you are logged in.
Then I recommend you to read this [article](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-create-private-route-with-react-router-v6-fa4b9d74cb55)